# Laravel - why eloquent does not use join?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

If I have this models

```
class Post extends Model{
    public function author()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Author ::class);
    }

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category ::class);
    }

}

class Author extends Model{

}

class Category extends Model{

}
```

and running this

```
$posts = Post::with('author', 'category')->get()
```

laravel runs 3 MySQL queries. For me, speed and performance is not really an issue here(although, it could be for someone), the issue is that if I want to sort posts by author name or category name I anyway need to join post and category manually and this is very awkward.

1.The first problem is that I need to worry about select

```
->select('posts.*')
```

e.g. id from category can be selected and hydrated into Post model.

2.The second problem is that I need to worry about groupBy
    ->groupBy('posts.id');
e.g. if the relation is hasOne and there are more than one categories for the post, the query will return more rows for categories.

3.The third problem is that I need to change all other wheres from

```
->where('date', $date)
```

to

```
->where('posts.date', $date)
```

because post and category can have date atributte without "ambiguous column" error can be thrown.

I think that running joins with eloquent can be very very awkward and error-prone. Does anyone have experience with other frameworks ORMs(it does not have to be PHP) which use join for eager loading and join for sorting related tables?

PS. for filtering related tables I don't need to use join but whereHas makes subqueries which are generally more slower than joins.

Comment: Don't your problems outline exactly why Eloquent wouldn't use joins?

Comment: @Devon yes, of course, you are right, but I am asking if another ORMs use joins(this mean that laravel eloquent is bad designed) or it is common practice that ORMs do not use joins...

Comment: I wouldn't say Eloquent is poorly designed, it accomplishes everything it sets out to do, and joins would create the problems you outline.  One thing Eloquent doesn't do out of box is sort by relations, but you can do this yourself.  I'll add a more detailed answer about how you do this without joins when I get a chance later today.

Comment: @Devon I know how to sort by relations with join(this is not a problem, there are many StackOverflow answers how to do that), my question is if eloquent can be better designed, because using joins with eloquent is really awkward...

Comment: An ORM that doesn't use joins for "with" queries is a joke.  Don't use Eloquent.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this issue with Laravel/Eloquent for a long time, and group bys, order bys, and performance are all part of the same design issue: Eloquent is for models and not for queries.

But, on the other hand, its an expressive language that can accomplish so much that it would be a waste to use DB::table('....')->join... or anything of the sort.

The solution which I'm most happy with is using the denormalized views pattern.

**Normalized Data** is data that is efficiently stored, and difficult to query when creating specialized views such as a concise list with a subset of columns, in a specific order or grouping.

on the other hand **denormalized data** is data that makes sense in only a single part of the application but it is formatted and ordered correctly.

This separation is important to understand since we overlook how easy it is to save *both* in our database. We simply need to decide how **consistent** our denormalized views and normalized data is.

To make a long story short, lets take an example: Artists, Albums, Songs - relationships should be clear to all readers.

I have a page in which I display a list of each artists first song, alphabetically ordered by artist last name, and in which album that song appears. Take a walk in your head on how to do this with eloquent. Ugh.
Additionally, I've asked my product team, and we've all come to the conclusion that the event in which a user sees this list is 100x more common than adding new albums to artists or new songs to albums, especially the FIRST SONG which has happened once for each new artist.

If only I had a table that I could run something simple like - FirstSong::orderBy('artist_last_name');

Instead of mucking about in the query, I eloquently update my first_songs view (or temporary table or actual table, doesn't matter). I plug in to the Song updated event, check to see that this song isn't the first, and if it is, I go and update my first_songs table. I even do this in a separate process, using Laravel's queues or whatever so even then my insert isn't impacted. I can even run a script once a day that recalculates the entire table - so there is a chance that first_songs isn't up-to-date from today's changes. Who cares?

**tl;dr**
Consider changing your architecture to having a separate pre-joined, view specific table for queries of this sort with its own model, instead of forcing the joins on normalized models.

Comment: I appreciate this answer but using denormalized data in the database is almost the same as using the elastic search, but solving my first problem in this direction pops up much more new problems like how to detect all changes in normalized data and update denormalized data, how you can be sure that denormalized data is up to date and much, what is convention when to use when not, and much more...I personally don't like use denormalized data but sometimes it is unavoidable.

Comment: of course, this isn't for every problem, but essentially "detecting changes to your normalized data" should be simple when using eloquent updated, saved, deleted events.

Comment: not simple like you think, if you run this 
Model::where('id', '>', 1)->update(['something' => 'something']);
updated event on model is not dispatched because query is performed directly on database...If you want cover all cases you must change all code from to $rows = Model::where('id', '>', 1)->get(); foreach($rows as $row){ $row->update(['something' => 'something']) } and this is also awkward...